# How to use the Fault Mediator to Respond with a Fault

Tags: rest, api, wso2, integrator

I am trying to use the WSO2 EI Fault mediator but the Fault Response always gives me a void response message. The point here is to try to build custom Fault messages. My Sample API code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/test" name="TestFaultAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{teste}">
        <inSequence>
            <log description="" level="full" separator=";">
                <property expression="get-property('uri.var.teste')" name="Path"/>
                <property expression="get-property('transport','Content-Type')" name="ContentType"/>
            </log>
            <filter xpath="get-property('uri.var.teste') != '1234'">
                <then>
                    <log description="" level="full">
                        <property name="Entrada" value="&quot;Fault Way&quot;"/>
                    </log>
                    <makefault description="" version="soap11">
                        <code value="soap11Env:Client" xmlns:soap11Env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
                        <reason value="Recruso incorreto"/>
                        <detail>incorrect Resource</detail>
                    </makefault>
                    <respond/>
                </then>
                <else>
                    <log level="full">
                        <property name="Caminho" value="&quot;Corret Way&quot;"/>
                    </log>
                    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                        <format>{&#xd;
"Status":"Correct Resource"&#xd;
}</format>
                        <args/>
                    </payloadFactory>
                    <respond/>
                </else>
            </filter>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence>
            <log level="full" separator=";">
                <property name="Caminho" value="&quot;Entrou Fault Sequence&quot;"/>
            </log>
            <property description="" name="HTTP_SC" scope="axis2" type="INTEGER" value="400"/>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>{&#xd;
"codigoErro":$1,&#xd;
"detalhe":$2&#xd;
}</format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('HTTP_SC','axis2')"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('ERROR_DETAIL')"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <respond/>
        </faultSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

So I have two questions:
1 - How can I make the custom fault messages response?
2 - Is it possible to use the fault mediator to change the sequence to the 'Fault Sequence' ?

Answer (score 1):

I will put the answers here. Those are results of my study and experiences:
1 - How can I make the custom fault messages response? 
      The way to do it is use filter mediator for test a rule and build the messages to respond your request.

2 - Is it possible to use the fault mediator to change the sequence to the 'Fault Sequence'?
      No. The fault sequence only start to be executed if a fault occurs. You can´t change the execution path by yourself using a mediator.

So It´s possible that other people with more experience then I answer different informations.
[],s
Marcello